# Swift UIBarButtonItem position that was created programatically

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I create a button using SwiftIcons, but the position of the icon is not correct. I add a negative width to fix it:

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem()
menuButton.setIcon(icon: .ionicons(.chevronLeft), iconSize: 24, color: .white, cgRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24), target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonClick))
let negativeSpacer:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
negativeSpacer.width = -13.7;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, menuButton]
```

This works for iOS 10 or lower, but on iOS 11 the width does not take negative values.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HxXW.png)
How can I fix this?
**Answer:**

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonClick))
menuButton.image = UIImage.init(icon: .ionicons(.chevronLeft), size: CGSize(width: 24, height: 24))
menuButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -13.7, 0, 0)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try by modifying edgeInsets for your button with this method :

```
UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right);
```

It allows you to add some padding on your barButtonItem.
Here is how you can use it with your actual code :

```
negativeSpacer.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -13.7, 0, 0);
```

Comment: No reaction to both positive and negative values applied to negativeSpacer or menuButton :(

Comment: But it works, when icon added as image for barButton, thanks!